# Объясните, пожалуйста, новичку что происходит в этой части кода

Tags: javascript

Вот решение задачи из учебника яваскрипт.ру про геттеры и сеттеры.

```js
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {

    firstName: {

      get: function() {
        return this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
      },

      set: function(newFirstName) {
        this.fullName = newFirstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }

    },

    lastName: {

      get: function() {
        return this.fullName.split(' ')[1];
      },

      set: function(newLastName) {
        this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + newLastName;
      }

    }

  });
}

var vasya = new User("Василий Попкин");

// чтение firstName/lastName
alert( vasya.firstName ); // Василий
alert( vasya.lastName ); // Попкин

// запись в lastName
vasya.lastName = 'Сидоров';

alert( vasya.fullName ); // Василий Сидоров
```

Интересует вот что. Здесь

```js
Object.defineProperties(this, {

    firstName: {

      get: function() {
        return this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
      },

      set: function(newFirstName) {
        this.fullName = newFirstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }
    }
```

..... как я понимаю присваиваются новые свойства объекта Юзер. Там, где get идет функция для превращения фразы в массив из 2х слов.  Там, где set - идет составление фразы из ???? (вот отсюда мне непонятно, что и как происходит).  Вопрос - почему именно аргумент newFirstName или newLastName, откуда он берется и где он передается в функцию? Почему именно так??

Comment: ну вы же свойство объекта создаете, и присваивает его, вот что присваиваете и становится этим аргументом функции. `vasya.firstName = "Василий"`, и попадет этот василий в функцию `set`

Comment: в качестве параметра сеттеру передается то, что вы присваиваете свойству. `vasya.lastName = 'Сидоров';` - тут "Сидоров" будет передано сеттеру в качестве параметра функции

Comment: т.е. по сути параметр newLastName это "сидоров" из vasya.lastName = 'Сидоров' ? Поскольку, в этой задаче по ее условию должна меняться только фамилия - то часть кода, где присваивается сеттером firstName можно переписать как                    set: function() {
        this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }  Верно?

Answer (score 0):

Читайте код внимательнее.
В строке:

```
 return this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
```

Полное имя сначала преобразуется в массив с использование разделителя пробел, а потом берётся первый элемент массива. Т.е. имя.

В строке:

```
this.fullName = newFirstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
```

собирается полное имя из нового имени переданного в функцию и фамилии уже заданной для элемента.
А newFirstName появится когда вы напишите:

```
vasya.firstName = "Вася";
```

Comment: Откуда переданного именно??? вот что для меня было непонятно

Comment: @Андрей Из правой части присвоения значения свойства.

Comment: Вот пишут: в качестве параметра сеттеру передается то, что вы присваиваете свойству. vasya.lastName = 'Сидоров'; - тут "Сидоров" будет передано сеттеру в качестве параметра функции – Вадим Лешкевич 33 минуты назад.  Т.е. по сути параметр newLastName это "сидоров" из vasya.lastName = 'Сидоров' ? Поскольку, в этой задаче по ее условию должна меняться только фамилия - то часть кода, где присваивается сеттером firstName можно переписать как set: function() { this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; } Верно?

Comment: @Андрей ну если задача такая, то да.

Comment: @Андрей Нет, нельзя. Эта функция (из Вашего комментария) ничего не делает.

Comment: Странно, но в моем представленном выше в коментарии исполнении код работает корректно и выводит то же, что и этот вариант set: function(newFirstName) {
        this.fullName = newFirstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }

Comment: А вы где нибудь пробовали написать vasya.firstName = "Вася";

Comment: @Андрей Этого не может быть. Вы чего-то не замечаете.